# Подключение только файлов .h к цели CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

У меня есть 2 динамические библиотеки, для удобства назову их Lib1 и Lib2. В Lib1 есть файл .h содержащий интерфейс класса. Я хочу в Lib2 реализовать этот интерфейс.
Есть ли возможность в CMake подключить или получить пути только публичных заголовочных файлов и при этом не линковать библиотеку Lib1 к Lib2? И на сколько правильно так делать?

Comment: Такая возможность есть. А правильнее вынести общие заголовочные в файлы в отдельную библиотеку.

Comment: @user7860670 Буду благодарен, если укажите как эту возможность использовать.

Comment: ¿А в чем состоит затруднение ее использовать? Если нет необходимости линковать библиотеку, то просто не делайте этого...

Comment: @user7860670 В то что я не знаю как это сделать. Я знаю, что можно включить директорию с *.h, прописав пути, но я искал способ, который будет похож на target_link_libraries. Чтобы можно было указать только имя или элиас, без указания относительного/абсолютного пути до директории с файлами

Comment: А этого в cmake в принципе нет, это же не система сборки и/или управления зависимостями.

Comment: @user7860670 Понял, спасибо